# osm2pgsql data converting: lost columns

Tags: openstreetmap, postgis

I've executed osm data converting using osm2pgsql from *.bz2 format to PostgreSQL database. But after converting I don't see such columns in table planet_osm_roads as: lanes, maxspeed.
Сan someone explain where are these columns? Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add the option `-k` when using osm2pgsql

```
osm2pgsql -d geodatabase -k planet.osm.bz2
```

> -k|--hstore       Add tags without column to an additional hstore (key/value) column to postgresql tables

Explanation: osm2pgsql imports normally the data in a static database schema. The tags without a corresponding column are ignored. By adding the option `-k` or `--hstore`, osm2pgsql will add a new hstore column `tags` to each table and save there all tags without column.

Depending of your needs, you can use the `-j` instead, which make osm2pgsql to save ALL tags in the `tags` column, this means, the tags with a database column too.

> -j|--hstore-all   Add all tags to an additional hstore (key/value) column in postgresql tables

After the import, to extract all maxspeed tags from the database, you can use query like this (in example):

```
SELECT osm_id, name, tags -> 'maxspeed' FROM planet_osm_roads;
```

where `tags` is the hstore column and `->` is a hstore operator.

See the Postgresql documentation for more infos about the hstore type and his operators: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/hstore.html

Comment: Thanks, this information helped me to decide my problem.

Answer (score 0):

This should better be a comment, however, I don't have enough reputation to do so: Instead of using .bz2, I recommend strongly to use .pbf, the "Protocolbuffer Binary Format", because: "It is about half of the size of a gzipped planet and about 30% smaller than a bzipped planet. It is also about 5x faster to write than a gzipped planet and 6x faster to read than a gzipped planet. The format was designed to support future extensibility and flexibility." More infos: http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/PBF_Format